# installing mail program in ubuntu 14.04

Tags: email

I'm using a software, after the execution MIT servers sent me an email. To receive this e-mail I need to install "mail" program in my ubuntu. I tried the below way but it didn't work;

```
sudo apt-get install mailutils
```

then I chose internet-Site configuration,
 and, System mail name:xxxx@xxx.edu.tr was set.

Is there a suitable way to setup "mail" program for receiving purposes?

the software's script to send an email is:

```
set umail = 'mail -s'
set JOBSTAT = `echo 'sh_gamit '$expt $yr[1] ${doy}`
  ${umail} "$JOBSTAT" ${mailto} < ${cpth}/tmp.mail.$ts >& /dev/null
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want to use a commandline tool to fetch mail to a local mailbox, I recommend fetchmail.

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure you use sh_gamit script from MIT, nice to hear it.
It uses `mail -s` command to send reports to users. And 'mail' is console mail client which can send message to any smtp server working in your system. So your task to properly configure smtp server for sending mail.

In my case it was sufficient to configure sendmail to use gmail credentials.
This manual looks quite good: https://developernote.com/2017/10/configuring-sendmail-with-gmail-relay-on-ubuntu-16-04/

Comment: It would be better to share the essential parts of the article here as well as just the link.  Links break and die with time.